# Need helping removing certain HTML tags from a file

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have HTML in a file that I want to remove. Here are the examples:

```
<a name="0.3__Toc308117073"></a>

<h1><a name="0.3__Toc308117071"></a><font color="#3B608D" size="4" face="Cambria"><b>Gains on Sales of Qualified Small Business Stock</b></font></h1>
```

I want to remove the anchor tags and I want to remove the h1 tags and everything in between. What would be the right syntax for a preg_replace or something similar?

Comment: on the example above: `$result = "\n\n";`

Comment: Don't use regexes for this. Use a HTML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify which parts are fixed, and which might differ from case to case. I'm especially interrested in the anchor name. Will "0.3_*Toc" be the only fixedpart, or is part of the number also fixed? What about 0.2*_Toc?

If it's ok for you to use two regexes, then use something like these patterns in this order:

```
<h1><a name="0.3__Toc\d*">.*</a>.*</h1>
<a name="0.3__Toc\d*">.*</a>
```

If you absolutely have to do it in one regex you'll have to advance that up with some lookarounds to catch both cases. And that's painfull (but fun, I guess). :)

Edit: Ok. I assumed you wanted only h1-tags with that sort of anchors as well as any loose anchors of that type. If the objective is to remove all h1-tags with content, and all anchor tags, you can use this instead:

```
(<h1>.*</h1>)|(<a name=".*">.*</a>)
```

So that would be a call to

```
preg_replace('/(<h1>.*<\/h1>)|(<a name=".*">.*<\/a>)/im', '', $htmlToStrip);
```

Comment: Just looking for <h1> *anything* </h1> and removing the whole block in one objective and then looking for <a name= *anything* </a> and removing that tag is the second objective. The anchor tags are found outside of the <h1> tags also so I apologize if that's confusing.

Comment: Maybe something like this...
`$regex = '<a name=".*__Toc\d*">.*</a>';
$content = preg_replace($regex,"",$content);`

and 

`$regex = '<h1>.*</h1>';
$content = preg_replace($regex,"",$content);`

Comment: I get `Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'h' in` when the script runs.

Comment: Sorry about that. Had to escape some slashes when doing regex in php it appears.

Comment: Final solution: `$content = preg_replace('@<h1[^>]*?>.*?<\/h1>@si', '', $content);
 $content = preg_replace('@<a name=[^>]*?>.*?<\/a>@si', '', $content);`

Answer (score 1):

From the something similar department: [QueryPath](http://querypath.org).

```
$html = htmlqp($html)
         ->top()->remove("a[name]")
         ->top()->remove("h1")
         ->top()->xhtml();
```

You can use a regex for this. But it's more work.

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx expression matches all tags (thus leaving you with the non-HTML):

```
/(<[^<>]+>)/
```

You could do a preg_match_all(). Realistically though, you should use an HTML parser as 'mario' and 'ThiefMaster' suggested.